# Android onClick method doesn't work and log my message

Tags: java, android

i just created my method onclick listener to log a simple message in the log but it doesn't respond at all and there aren't any errors or exception.

[image: here's my bunch of code]

[image: here's the onClick listener]

Comment: Please post the code into the question instead of in images.  That makes it much easier for people to review.  Here's a guide for writing a good Question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Post both your java and xml file along with the question

Comment: You're looking at the Gradle event logs, not the Android monitor where the logcat is

Comment: it is not the app log section.open logcat to see your log

Comment: you are looking at wrong window open `logcat` to check

Comment: Thank you, dude, I appreciate your effort to answer my question it works now after looking at the correct window but there was another issue so my button did not respond to my on click method. the error was in my xml file (this view is not constrained) error and I solved it you can follow this: 
Right-click on the widget> Constraint Layout > Infer Constraints https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOur51u5Nk0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it isn't work but I don't like this kind of usage of onClick method. I saw that ID of your button is "button" in the second SS. You can use code below in onCreate() method of your activity:

```
Button someNamedButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    someNamedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("Some tag", "Some message");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey he/she is looking at wrong window, nothing wrong with the code

Comment: Thanks, dude I appreciate your efforts it works fine now have a look at the solution in the comments of the above answer